# Create products (configurable and simple) and set custom options

Tags: php, magento

I'm attempting to create a configurable product, associate it with a simple product, and add custom options to the simple product.
I'm successfully creating the products and associations, but I haven't been able to add the custom options to them.

I saw a question somebody posted using `Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option_api')`, however I can't seem to find that model.
Any ideas on how to get this done?

My code is below, and the custom options part is near the bottom.

```
$parentProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$parentProduct->setAttributeSetId(4)
    ->setTypeId('configurable')
    ->setStockData(array(
        'manage_stock'  => 0,
        'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
        'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
    ))
    ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setTaxClassId(1)
    ->setCreatedAt(time())
    ->setName($row['name'])
    ->setSku($sku)
    ->setPrice($row['price'])
    ->setCategoryIds(array(2))
    ->setStatus(1)
    ->setWeight(1)
    ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
    ->setDescription($row['description'])
    ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc']);

try
{
    $parentProduct->save();

    $parent_id = $parentProduct->getId();
    echo 'Product created: ' . $parent_id . "\n";

    if (!empty($parent_id))
    {
        $color = 0;
        $child_ids = array();

        foreach ($row['children'] as $child_sku => $child)
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
            $product->setAttributeSetId(4)
                ->setTypeId('simple')
                ->setStockData(array(
                    'manage_stock'  => 0,
                    'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
                    'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
                ))
                ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
                ->setTaxClassId(12)
                ->setCreatedAt(time())
                ->setName($row['name'] . ' ' . (($color == 0) ? 'Silver' : 'Gold'))
                ->setSku($sku . $child_sku)
                ->setPrice($row['price'])
                ->setcategoryIds(array(3))
                ->setStatus(1)
                ->setWeight(1)
                ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
                ->setDescription($row['description'])
                ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc'])
                ->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);

            foreach ($child['options'] as $select_id => $selectrow)
            {
                $options = array(
                    'type'      => 'select',
                    'title'     => array(
                        'title' => $sku . '_CLASSIC',
                    ),
                );

                foreach ($selectrow['lines'] as $linetitle => $line)
                {
                    $options['type_title'][]['title'] = $linetitle;
                    $options['type_value'][]['min_chars'] = $line[0];
                    $options['type_value'][]['max_chars'] = $line[1];
                }

                $product->setCustomOptions($options);
            }

            $product->save();

            $color = ($color == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            $product_id = $product->getId();
            $child_ids[] = $product_id;
            echo 'Simple product created: ' . $product_id . "\n";
        }


        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable $resource */
        $resource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
            ->saveProducts($parent_id, $child_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this And pass your options values in my $value_arrays array.

```
 $product->setAttributeSetId(4)
            ->setTypeId('simple')
            ->setStockData(array(
                'manage_stock'  => 0,
                'min_sale_qty'  => 0,
                'max_sale_qty'  => 0,
            ))
            ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->setTaxClassId(12)
            ->setCreatedAt(time())
            ->setName($row['name'] . ' ' . (($color == 0) ? 'Silver' : 'Gold'))
            ->setSku($sku . $child_sku)
            ->setPrice($row['price'])
            ->setcategoryIds(array(3))
            ->setStatus(1)
            ->setWeight(1)
            ->setWebsiteIDs(array(1))
            ->setDescription($row['description'])
            ->setShortDescription($row['short_desc'])
            ->setHasOptions(1); 

$value_arrays = array();
$opt = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option');
$opt->setProduct($product);
$value_arrays[] =  array('is_delete'     => 0,
             'title'         => 'title',
             'price_type'    => 'fixed',
             'price'         => 'price',
             'sku'           => 'product sku',
             'option_type_id'=> -1,);
$optionArray = array(
        'is_delete' => 0,
        'title' => 'title',
        'previous_group' => '',
        'previous_type' => '',
        'type' => 'drop_down',  //can be radio, drop_down, file, area...
        'is_require' => 0,
        'sort_order' => 0,
        'values' => $value_arrays );

$opt->addOption($optionArray);
$opt->saveOptions();
$product->Save();
```

Comment: If I had `$product->save()` after adding the options, I would get an error, but having it before, I get no custom options at all.

Comment: might be the problem belongs to the product ...means before adding the custom option we need to save that and then again load that product by the product ID and then save....Hope you understand what i am trying to say..